# IE8 resets some margins to 0 when triggering a click Javascript event

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have 3 divs with content which get their visibility triggered by clicking on 3 buttons:

http://screencast.com/t/NSlRzrIBBUb

Sometimes when I click one of the buttons I get this:

http://screencast.com/t/wjw3565BBGQ

It's like some margins get reset to 0. Even the line-height and letter-spacing seem to reset. After clicking anywhere on the screen everything returns back to normal. Everything works fine on all other browsers.

Does anybody have an ideea why?

Thanks,
Lucian

Comment: I've seen IE jump stuff around kind of like that when using `position:relative` in certain situations. Anything like that in your CSS?

Comment: We can give you all the wild guesses you want and, without any code, we can't do anything else.

Comment: It's production for several months: http://www.chiaroluce.it/chiaro-luce-vetri-300.php

Answer (score 0):

visibility:hidden/visible causes a [repaint if you toggle it using a class reference, or a reflow](http://www.stubbornella.org/content/2009/03/27/reflows-repaints-css-performance-making-your-javascript-slow/) if you toggle it using a `style` attribute.

Use a `position:relative` container to wrap each of the 3 divs. Make each of the 3 divs `position:absolute`. On click, add a class the sets `top:-9999px`.